# Using SED to insert a string into a line at a specific location

Tags: sed

I have to update the spf record in multiple clients zone files.

The existing spf record would look something like this:

```
"v=spf1 +a +mx +ip4:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx +include:spf.web-xxx.com ~all"
```

What I need to do is insert a new ip address following the v=spf1 +a +mx

The desired output would be

```
"v=spf1 +a +mx +ip4:yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy +ip4:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx +include:spf.web-xxx.com ~all"
```

I'm trying this command:

```
sed  '/v=spf1 +a +mx /a +ip4:yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy' myfile
```

But it appends the new ip to the end of the line

So I tried:

```
sed  '/v=spf1 +a +mx /i +ip4:67.215.1.206' myfile
```

but I get the same result.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Any help appreciated.

Kerry

Comment: Welcome, could it be that you want to insert more than one ip?

Comment: not really, i just need to insert one ip into the record. Various files I update may already have multiple ips already there

Comment: It would be easier to tell sed to replace the space after +mx with  +ip4:67.215.1.206 instead of using insert or append... use it as a regular search/replace.

Answer (score 2):

In GNU `sed` insert `i` and append `a` commands add *new lines*. You are looking for substituting a string in the *same line*, hence you need the substitute command `s`.

[From the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html):

> **i text**
>
> insert text before a line (alternative syntax).
>
> **a text**
>
> Appending text after a line. This is a GNU extension to the standard a command - see below for details.

For example

```bsh
$ echo foo | sed ibar
bar
foo
$ echo foo | sed abar
foo
bar
```

Try something like this assuming the lines have always the same format:

```bsh
$ sed 's/+/+ip4:127.0.0.1 +/4' file
"v=spf1 +a +mx +ip4:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx +ip4:127.0.0.1 +include:spf.web-xxx.com ~all"
```

It finds the 4th plus sign `+`

```
"v=spf1 +a +mx +ip4:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx +..."
```

and substitutes it for a plus sign `+` and the ip.